# How to Modify a String in Arm Assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, infix-notation

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add spaces to an infix expression so that something like 3+5 would turn into 3 +5. I keep on getting a segmentation fault and I can't even pinpoint which line the error is coming from because for some reason, I can't print out anything also. Here's my code for reference:

```
.data
 
.balign 4
return: .word 0
 
.balign 4
operations: .asciz "+-*/^"
 
.balign 4
    output: .space 100
 
.balign 4
    spa: .asciz " "
.text
.global printf
.global main
 
main:
    ldr r0, [r1, #4] //load address of first character in expression
    ldr r1, =return
    str lr, [r1] //store lr in return variable
    ldr r2,=output //load address of output on r2
    ldr r3, =spa //load address of space variable
    ldr r3, [r3] //load character ' ' onto r3
 
loop:
    cmp r0, #0 //check if reached end of input
    beq end //if so go to end
    ldr r1, =operations //load the address of  operations string in r1
 
loop2:;
    cmp r1, #0 //check if reached end of operation string
    beq loop3 //means the current character in output isn't an operator
    ldr r5, [r1] //else load value of r1 in r5, the current operator
    ldr r6, [r0] //load current value in input string to r6
    cmp r5, r6 //compare the two values
    beq loop3 //if equal go to loop3
    add r1, r1, #1 //if not increment address of r1
    b loop2 //start next iteration of loop2
 
loop3:
    str r3, [r2] //since current character is an operator, store space first
    add r2, r2, #1
    b loop4 //on output string. Then go to loop4
 
 
loop4:
    str r6, [r2] //store the current character, stored in r6, in r2
    add r0, r0, #1 //increment address of r0 by 1 to get to next character
    add r2, r2, #1 //increment address of r2 by one to get to next slot in array
    b loop //start next iteration of loop
 
end:
    ldr r0, =output //load address of output onto r0
    bl printf //print out string
    ldr lr, =return //restore link register
    ldr lr, [lr]
    bx lr
```

Comment: Obvious issue is that you only load the addresses and never the characters. Also characters are 1 byte so use `LDRB` and `STRB`.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much. That was the problem!!! I don't how i keep on forgetting. The whole issue with ldrb and strb happened to me before.

Comment: The connection to [tag:prefix-notation] escapes me. Don't tag indiscriminately.